# Why am I obtaining these alter database error trying to create a DB using a DDL script obtained from SQL Server 2012 on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am pretty new to SQL Server, and I am finding the following difficulties.

I extract the DDL to create a database from a SQL Server 2012 machine, then I run this DDL creating the database on an old SQL Server 2008 instance, and I am getting the following errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'FILESTREAM'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME'.

The first error is on this line:

```
ALTER DATABASE [SIGLA-AZIENDA_SIGLA-AOO] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
GO
```

The second error is on this line:

```
ALTER DATABASE [SIGLA-AZIENDA_SIGLA-AOO] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS 
GO
```

What could be the causes of these error? Is related to the different version of SQL Server? From what I know the involved project is not using something like **BLOB** field so I think that FILESTREAM are not mandatory.

How can I try to solve these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is related to the SQL Server version.

`FileStream` was introduced in 2012 as documented in the [Alter database set options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) page:

> `<FILESTREAM_option>` ::=
>   Applies to: SQL Server ( SQL Server 2012 (11.x) through SQL Server 2017)

Same goes for `target_recovery_time` (documented in the same page):

> `<target_recovery_time_option>` ::=
>   Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2012 (11.x) through SQL Server 2017)

Answer (score 2):

Because the SQL Server features supporting is different through the versions.

To solve your problem click the **Advanced** button from the **Set Scripting Options** dialog, and change the **Script for Server Version** to **SQL Server 2008**, then we can get the script for **SQL Server 2008** Database like below:
[image: guide image]

This msdn link is about another problem similar to yours:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1d75d41-d755-4a43-aaa7-2a109477177b/errors-on-script-while-parsing?forum=sqlexpress